# Calling a static function on a parameter class in a template while forwarding arguments

Tags: templates, c++11

Say I have a series of classes with private constructors and which must be allocated through dedicated `New(...)` static functions like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
  static Foo* New();
private:
  Foo() {}
};

class Bar {
public:
  static Bar* New(int a, int b);
private:
  Bar() {}
};
```

I want to write a template class to call their `New(...)` static functions in a generic way:

```
template<class T, typename... Args>
class Test {
public:
  static Test<T> Make(Args&&... args) {
    return Test<T>(T::New(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

private:
  inline Test(T* object) : m_object(object) {}

  T* m_object;
};
```

So that I can do:

```
auto foo = Test<Foo>::Make();
auto bar = Test<Bar>::Make(1, 2);
```

The `Foo` case without arguments work, but not the `Bar` case. Clang says that it expects `New()` to take no arguments as if the arguments were not forwarded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** Here's a real-life error from Clang with my `Buffer` class when attempting to call `Test<Buffer>::Make(1000)`:

```
Buffer.hpp:25:29: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument 'string', but no arguments were provided
    inline static BufferRef New(const char (&string)[N]) {  // For literal strings
                            ^
Buffer.hpp:16:29: note: candidate function not viable: requires single argument 'length', but no arguments were provided
    inline static BufferRef New(size_t length) {
                            ^
Buffer.hpp:29:29: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least argument 'string', but no arguments were provided
    inline static BufferRef New(const char* string, bool copy = true) {
                            ^
Buffer.hpp:33:29: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least argument 'string', but no arguments were provided
    inline static BufferRef New(const std::string& string, bool copy = true) {
                            ^
Buffer.hpp:20:29: note: candidate function not viable: requires at least 2 arguments, but 0 were provided
    inline static BufferRef New(void* bytes, size_t length, bool copy = true) {
```

Comment: How do you instantiate `Test`?

Comment: I realized I had a type in my sample code above, it's fixed: `auto bar = Test<Bar>::Make(1, 2);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - the variadic template arguments "obviously" need to be on the static function, not the class itself:

```
template<class T>
class Test {
public:
  template<typename... Args>
  static Test<T> Make(Args&&... args) {
    return Test<T>(T::New(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  }

private:
  inline Test(T* object) : m_object(object) {}

  T* m_object;
};
```